# C# Change value of local variable - stack representation

Tags: c#, memory, stack

I have a question about variables on stack in C#, look at example below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int a = 1; //this element goes to the stack as the first one 
     int b = 2; //second element in the stack
     a = 4;
     a++;
}
```

How it's possible to change value of variable "a" without pop the variable "b" from stack ?

I will be grateful if someone explain me how it works in this case ?

Comment: Stack is LIFO, you need to pop out data to access the earlier entries, though you may show some code of what you are trying and may use a different data structure based on the requirement

Comment: It's better to put code in the question as text, and not as image.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my question is different - I know that stack works like you describe but how it's  possible to get acces to variable "b" if this variable have to be pop out to change value of variable "a" ?

Comment: Is the above, only code you have, since that would mean you are talking about .Net stack allocation of value types, where you can indeed access any variable anytime or are you creating a stack data structure to work

Answer (score 1):

The memory construct that .NET uses to hold value types is indeed called 'the stack', but it doesn't mean that each and every variable is held in a LIFO structure, where you can only access the last one.

So to answer your question - when you need to access the variable `a` - CLR does that exactly (i.e. accesses it directly), there's no need to pop anything here.

You can read more about it, for example, here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-heaping-vs-stacking-in-net-part-i/.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are indeed located on stack, but compiler hides the stack from you. Basically, it translates your variables into addresses relative to the top of the stack. In your example, compiler knows that b is the last thing on the stack, and a one before last.

When a function is executed, one register (SP on classic 8086 processor, now it's probably ESP or something) points to the address at the top of the stack. Function arguments and local variables are addressed as [SP+n], where n is the number of bytes from top of the stack.